# Problems with the Wireless mouse/ USB ports in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I have a Wireless Microsoft Mouse on a Windows 7(64-bit) PC, and a normal PS2 keyboard attached to it. The problem is with Wireless mouse which stops working frequently (every 2-3 weeks). Initially thought the mouse and changed batteries, but later found after reboot it does work without changing batteries. Also whenever it happens, the computer takes ages to shut down and I end up doing cold restart.

Is it the USB ports or problem with drivers? Any suggestions ?

Note : Whenever it stops responding, I try to use a normal PS2 & USB mouse but never works until I restart the computer.

Comment: USB3 can interfere with 2.4GHz wireless mice.
I've tried several different USB3 hubs with a couple of different Microsoft wireless mice, and the result is erratic behavior. First I thought that the hub I was using was defective, because I don't see this problem when the mouse dongle is plugged into the USB3 port directly on my laptop. Now I've found that plugging the mouse into a cheap USB3 extension cable results in even worse erratic behavior. See also: https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1004004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the USB port(s) you are using may have a power-saving mode activated. This would set the mouse to "sleep" and you may be having some wake-up issues because of that.

Anyway, open your start menu and type in "Change power-saving settings" and open up the dialogue. Here, search around and make sure that your USB ports do not have Power Saving (Sleeping) enabled.

Once you've changed it, restart the system and see if it's fixed. If not:

Click on your start menu button, type in Device Manager and click on it when it shows up in the search results.

Browser over to your USB Hubs and Ports and go through all of them to make sure that none of them have "power-saving" activated in the Advanced tab (this is from memory, so just check around in each of the components 'properties' dialogue).

You may also check to see if you're running any third party power management tools if none of these solve your problem.

Comment: Windows Update to Service pack1 solved the problem for me.